# Swift get Idfa crash

Tags: swift, crash, idfa

```
ASIdentifierManager.shared().advertisingIdentifier.uuidString
```

EXC_CRASH when get idfa.

Xcode terminal Print

> LaunchServices: disconnect event (interruption) received for service
>   com.apple.lsd.advertisingidentifiers

Comment: Can you provide the steps to reproduce the error? Or share your code where you have placed this piece line.

Comment: I have pasted the code above. Crash not occured every times.

Answer (score 0):

Someone report bugs on swift.org
https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6143